# Number of times a button pressed, should be multiply with variable(recipeTotal) value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm working on the Angular 8 application. I want to multiply the numbers of times the button pressed with the existing value of (recipetotal). But it didn't give me correct result.

The result should be => 8*3=24
But the result I'm getting is => 48

Can someone please help me with this.

**My TS Code**

```
  quantityControl(flag) {

    if (flag == '+') {
      this.quantity = this.quantity + 1;
      if (this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice === 0) {
        this.recipeTotal = this.recipeTotal * this.quantity;
        console.log('The price is:'+ this.recipeTotal);
      }
    } else {
      if (this.quantity != 1) {
        this.quantity = this.quantity - 1;
        if (this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice === 0) {
          this.recipeTotal = this.recipeTotal * this.quantity;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**My HTML Code**

```
 <div class="u-line">
      <div class="product-quantity padding-10"><span class="text-light-black fw-700 fs-16">Quantity</span>
        <div class="input-group quantity">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button (click)="quantityControl('-')" class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="text-center" [(ngModel)]="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button (click)="quantityControl('+')" class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><i
              class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mistake is in this function evaluating

```
if (this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice === 0)
```

Past it code or check it by yourself.

Comment: The problem is with 'recipetotal' variable. When the button is clicked once, its get multiplied with it. But when the button is pressed twice or three time. The previously stored value of 'recipetotal' got multiplied. The 'recpietotal' value got increased itself once the button is clicked

Comment: Try to debug with console log if first time pressed this condition "this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice === 0" is true.

It's good to check if in else condition "this.quantity" is not equal to 0

Comment: Well, as the variable 'recipetotal' is inside if condition. It gave me the same answer inside the console also

Comment: Should be also event propagation problem, try to prevent it with jquery code to trap event only one time --> $("button").click(function(){
  $("p").off("click");
});